# How to do incremental learning on MobileNet-SSD caffe

Tags: conv-neural-network, caffe, mobilenet

I'm training my classifier on *20k* images but every week I get more new pictures so I want to incrementally train my previous model(last stopped iteration) instead of retraining *20k+new_images* on all the images again which is a waste of time and compute

I figured out incremental training with Yolo but can't seem to find anything for MobileNet-SSD caffe implemented here https://github.com/chuanqi305/MobileNet-SSD

To understand more about what I'm talking about refer to this: 
[How to do incremental training on the basis of yolov3.weights](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/705) & answer to this mention [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/829#issuecomment-389831486):

```
 darknet.exe partial cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights yolov3.conv.105 105
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass previous iteration in `train.sh` instead of 73000 iteration. The new iteration are found in snapshot folder once you are done training

```
if ! test -f example/MobileNetSSD_train.prototxt ;then
echo "error: example/MobileNetSSD_train.prototxt does not exist."
echo "please use the gen_model.sh to generate your own model."
exit 1
fi
mkdir -p snapshot

#Initiate a new training
$CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/caffe train -solver="solver_train.prototxt" \
-weights="mobilenet_iter_73000.caffemodel" \
-gpu 0
```

Comment: Quick question. When I do incremental learning in caffe like that, what dataset do I use? (in this example the previous 20k + new data, or just the new data)